# Loading Bootstrap modal with jQuery inside - breaks original modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a Bootstrap modal that is using requireJS to load jQuery inside and run JS, that show output in modal.

This setup works great for first opening of the modal. If I close the modal and try to open it again:

```
$("#modalLogin").modal();
```

I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

It seems that loading of jQuery inside of modal  is breaking jQuery modal functionality of main page. Is there a way to re-enable .modal() method in original page, once I close the modal?

Comment: I am using the modals too but I always write inside `modal()` function a keyword either `hide` or `show` and it is working every time. Did you try to open and close a blank modal? Did you debug removing query from inside (why are you loading it also there?)

Comment: I can open and close empty modal without problems. Opening modal stops working when I load content into modal.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but what is the content? Is that the query you said also? Or did you try that without including query again?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [boostrap modal's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals),

You can call .modal() to initiate it, with or without options,

But you have to precise the method when you want to open / hide it :

```
$('#modalLogin').modal('show');
```